# What should I do when I want to make my picturebox collide in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a quite simple game that helps to understand simple logic with children while playing. It is in a very early stage now.

First look at the picture below

[image: The picture]

The Maroon colored square is the player object now, it is a 40x40 picture box
The background is a 600x600 panel with a set background image, where I drew the first map (i want to make more maps later, this is going to be the first "tutorial map")

I have 4 buttons now:

One will move the player forward - now it only moves the player square up

One will move the player backward - now it only moves the player square down

One will turn the player right - not yet functioning

One will turn the player left - not yet functioning

I already made that my player never leaves the panel no matter what but:

I want to know how can I make that my player wont move when there is a wall (green square) front of it. - Now it goes through the green wall, and i want it to only move on the white field.

Should I use some kind of objects and put them there as walls?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can use matric. I don't know what data structure are you using but matrix suits well in here. objects in matric will tell whether its wall or road. so don't move object if that's wall. matric can have numbers. interpret `1` as road, `0` as wall. btw you should put some code here if you want help and have trouble fixing your code

Answer (score 0):

You have the panel, which is divided by 225 40x40 squares. So your panel has 15 squares width and 15 squares height. You can create a 15x15 matrix, where every cell can be 0 or 1 (0 is a coridor and 1 is a wall):

```
int[,] Matrix = new int[15, 15];
```

This matrix will represent your world collisions. After you have pressed a button, you should check your new player location, if it collides with matrix or out of bounds:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Right:
            if ((int)PlayerLocation.X + 1 != Matrix.GetLength(1) && Matrix[(int)PlayerLocation.Y, (int)PlayerLocation.X + 1] == 0)
            {
                PlayerLocation = new Point(PlayerLocation.X + 1, PlayerLocation.Y);
                MovePlayer();
            }
            break;
        case Key.Left:
            if ((int)PlayerLocation.X != 0 && Matrix[(int)PlayerLocation.Y, (int)PlayerLocation.X - 1] == 0)
            {
                PlayerLocation = new Point(PlayerLocation.X - 1, PlayerLocation.Y);
                MovePlayer();
            }
            break;
        case Key.Up:
            if ((int)PlayerLocation.Y != 0 && Matrix[(int)PlayerLocation.Y - 1, (int)PlayerLocation.X] == 0)
            {
                PlayerLocation = new Point(PlayerLocation.X, PlayerLocation.Y - 1);
                MovePlayer();
            }
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            if ((int)PlayerLocation.Y + 1 != Matrix.GetLength(0) && Matrix[(int)PlayerLocation.Y + 1, (int)PlayerLocation.X] == 0)
            {
                PlayerLocation = new Point(PlayerLocation.X, PlayerLocation.Y + 1);
                MovePlayer();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```